# Mongoose Query Using Multiple ObjectIds (with 'ref')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is it possible in Mongoose to perform a query whereby two of the search parameters are ObjectIds (one being a ref)?

For example, given the following schemas:

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;

var fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
});

schemas.Foo = mongoose.model("Foo", fooSchema, "foo");

var barSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    fooId : { type: ObjectId, ref: "Foo" },
    ...
});

schemas.Bar = mongoose.model("Bar", barSchema, "bar");
```

I would expect this to work:

```
        schemas.Bar.find({ 

             _id        : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.barId),
             fooId      : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.fooId)

           }, 
           function(err, result)
           {
             ...
           }
        );
```

But it returns an empty set. Curiously, if I remove one or the other of the criteria it works.

```
        schemas.Bar.find({ 

             _id        : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.barId)

           }, ...);
```

or...

```
        schemas.Bar.find({ 

             fooId          : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.fooId)

           }, ...);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can see the raw data in the database, yet the query is always empty if I use both ObjectIds in the same find.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well damn, I just solved it after a few hours of staring at my screen.

When you insert a Bar document you have to explicitly tell Mongoose the ref value in question is an ObjectId seemingly, even if that value has come from a Foo instance where _id is defined as an ObjectId! Go figure.. I guess Mongoose coerces it to a String otherwise?

```
   (new schemas.Bar({

        fooId : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(somePreviouslyRetrievedFoo._id),
        ...
    })).save(...)
```

Finally, it works! Hope this helps others tripping up on it!